# How do I find out that Amazon ElasticSearch service is used instead of casual ES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am writing my tool for Elasticsearch and have found out that when working with Amazon that some parts work differently. So I am writing custom handlers for that. 
But is there a way I can determine that ES cluster is on AWS ES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the hostname: if you're running on AWS Managed Elasticsearch it will end with `es.amazonaws.com`.

You can also look at the results of a top-level GET (and should), to find the version and whether or not it's running the open-source edition.

```
{
  "name" : "xxxxxx",
  "cluster_name" : "123456789012:xxx",
  "cluster_uuid" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.8.0",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "dadef69",
    "build_date" : "2020-04-28T01:07:12.310753Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```